# Rank players based on their selections

Tags: algorithm, ranking

I am working on a game where I am giving every player a  set of statements with each statement having 3 different options. Every player is asked to select one of the 3 options for each statement. Now, based on the options that the user has selected and based on what others have selected, I am trying to rank them.

Now, the problem is that I am unable to come up with a fair ranking algorithm. I am sure this problem would have already been solved by someone in one way or other so looking for an existing method/algorithm that can be used to rank people.

Example,

> Lets say Q1 have 3 options namely op1, op2 and op3. Based on the existing records, op1 is selected by 38%, op2 is selected by 42% and op3 is selected by 30%. Now a new user (lets call him player1) is playing the game and he selected op2. How should I assign points to him such that I can build a leader board of all the people. What if, later equation changes and op1 becomes 50%, op2 becomes 10% and op3 becomes 40%. Do I need to update the scores of player1 ?